# Android - At Minutes to a Time hh.mm.ss

Tags: java, android, date, time

i,ve got a problem which i cant solve at the moment.
I already googled for it and found some solutions, but all of them not rly match my problem.

So i get 2 Strings from SQL Database in the format hh:mm:ss.

The first String is a time, for example "14:30:00" and the second String is a value of minutes for example "00:15:00"

Now i wanna add the second Time to the first time.
After that i'll try to substract the actual time from this time to get the difference.

All of this should work without a Date, just the time.

Would be nice if someone could help me

Comment: If it is every time the same format `hh:mm:ss` you could split the string at the ` : `

Comment: Is it a *time-of-day* or is it an *elapsed time*?  Or perhaps one of each?  They are different concepts.

Comment: @Stevetro The question in comment by Matt Johnson is critical. Are you representing something like "An event began at half-past two and lasted for fifteen minutes duration, what is the ending time?".

Comment: Getting the difference is not directly supported in Android unless you use an external library or apply your home-grown workaround. Do you want the difference in minutes only, or in hours-minutes-seconds? And are you really sure to not care about the date? For example adding minutes/hours to a local time can cause the time rolling around midnight resulting in a local time earlier than the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a 'time' without a date is not valid.
Think about daylight saving time etc.

One solution is maybe to create two date objects (with a fixed date) and use them for your calculation.
Or parse the string and use TimeUnit to work with the values.

Keep in mind that you **can't** just sum the parts of your timestring one by one (e.g. 20:45:58 + 00:20:10 = 20:05:08 ) !

So if you decide to parse, make your life easier and use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html
to bring your values to a base (seconds) do your calculations and bring the result to the format you wish.

The Calendar class can also be a solution (but keep daylight saving in mind!):

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( date );
cal.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20 );
cal.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 15 );
cal.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
cal.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );
cal.add( Calendar.MINUTE, 22 );
date = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: yeah i think the best idea is to use a fixed date and just add the other time .

Answer (score 1):

If it is every time the same format `hh:mm:ss` you could split the string at the `:`. Then remove the `:` and convert the string to an integer. Now you can add the 3 int values( one for hours, one for minutes, one for seconds) to the second string which was also splited like this.
It is kind of patchy because you are working with strings, but it will work.